# Name capitalization in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I have problem with name capitalization. Should I use before_save callback?
I added 2 columns to model generated by devise - first_name and last_name. What now? help please:)

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to do anything `before_save`, although it is an option. What I typically do is create a method on the user model to provide this functionality. Like:

```
  # models/user.rb
  def capitalize_name
    "#{first_name.capitalize} #{last_name.capitalize}"
  end
```

Then anywhere you want to use it just use:

```
  current_user.capitalize_name
```

or whatever the current_user object is .capitalize_name

Answer (score 0):

You can use before_save if you want the names to be capitalized in your database and if you do not want to call capitalize_names everywhere in your view.

```
before_save :capitalize_names

def capitalize_names
  first_name.capitalize!
  last_name.capitalize!
end
```

Comment: where do i put it? im using devise and i dont see users controller;/

Comment: you should be having a user model or something similar to that right?